# Why does Safari take ~ 30MB of RAM while Firefox takes ~ 300MB?

Tags: macos, firefox, memory, safari, macos-mojave

I am wondering if the Activity Monitor does not work correctly. In both cases I had the browser open with one tab pointed to Google.com

Neither browser has any additional extensions installed and both are up to date as of 05/13/19 ( Firefox Quantum and Safari 12.1 )

[image: Safari Screen Shot]

[Related Q/A for Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/1436355/why-does-firefox-take-nearly-1gb-of-ram-just-to-open-one-tab)

Comment: Please edit your question to add what version of macOS, Safari and Firefox you are using. The version of Safari (12.1) I am using on macOS Mojave (10.14.4) shows around 55MB being used and Firefox (66.0.5) shows around 250MB being used.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point ... as even with your particular setup there is a 5x difference in memory usage.

Comment: We cannot answer this question here. I'd imagine those two numbers are measuring different things in some ways, and I know that only FF and Safari devs can provide the information necessary to give a definitive answer as to why their products have such different memory footprints.

Answer (score 0):

Expect to see more efficient use when your application is developed by the same company that developed the OS.

In this case Apple developed both macOS and Safari.

Comment: It isn't clear why that would explain it.